# Box issue in Chrome versus Firefox

Tags: css

In Chrome, notice that that `input` area under "Your contact info" lines up with the border for `div#contact`. Also notice that the textarea under "Message" does not line up with that border; it's moved in a couple pixels. This is not the behavior I prefer.
[image: Chrome screencap]

In Firefox, everything lines up on the left. It's a little difficult, but you can see that in this screencap. This is the behavior I prefer.
[image: Firefox screencap]

My problem is obvious: how do I get those input areas to line up on the left (as in the Firefox image)?

Here is the HTML (non-working skeleton `form` code) that's rendered for that portion of the page (which resides in the footer of the page).

```
<div id="footer">   
  <div id="contact"> 
    <h1>Talk to me</h1> 
      <div id="email-me">You can email me at <a href="mailto:address@server.com">address@server.com</a><br/> 
      or fill out the form below!
    </div> 
    <form> 
      <div id="email"> 
        <h2>Your contact info</h2> 
        <input type="text"/><br/> 
      </div> 
      <div id="message"> 
        <h2>Message</h2> 
        <textarea rows="10" cols="75"></textarea><br/> 
      </div> 
      <input class="buttons" type="submit" value="Send"/> 
    </form> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Here's the CSS. It's quite long, so I was going to edit out some parts, but I decided against it in case some small piece makes the difference.

```
#footer {
    clear:both;
    background-color:#8BA5B5;
    min-height:400px;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Helvetica,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    padding-left:105px;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:45px;
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

  #footer h1 {
    font-size:15px;
    margin:0px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }

  #footer a {
    color:#DAEBF5;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }

    #footer a:visited {
        color:#333;
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    #footer a:hover {
      text-decoration:underline;
    }

  #email-me {
    font-size:16px;
    padding-left:2px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
  }

    #email-me a {
      font-size:18px;
      font-style:normal;
    }

  #contact {
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-style:oblique;
    font-family:georgia,times,serif;
  }

    #contact h1 {
      font-size:44px;
      font-style:normal;
      text-align:center;
      font-family:helvetica,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    }

    #contact h2 {
      margin:0px;
      font:inherit;
    }

    #contact input {
        background-color:transparent;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        color:#fff;
        width:50%;
    }

    #contact textarea {
        background-color:transparent;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        color:#fff;
    }

    #contact #message {
      margin-top:5px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
    }

    #contact .buttons {
      font-family:inherit;
      font-weight:800;
      font-size:12px;
      padding:5px;
      width:100%;
      background-color:#fff;
      color:#8BA5B5;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that your margins are off... Are you using a CSS reset to level the style across all browsers?

try setting **margin:0;** to your inputs

For a css reset, I recommend:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Another CSS to look at is https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/
From the readme: Normalize.css is a customisable CSS file that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. We researched the differences between default browser styles in order to precisely target only the styles that need normalizing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #contact input, #contact textarea { 
    margin:0px;
}
```